# LINQ TO Entities OrderBy Conundrum

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am having trouble trying to understand how to perform an order by in a LINQ to Entities call to return data organized in the desired order.  The database used is postgresql.  The order by in postgres is:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    part
ORDER BY
    split_part(partnumber, '-',1)::int
    , split_part(partnumber, '-',2)::int
```

Partnumber is a string field which is formated into 2-3 segments which are numeric separated by '-'.  eg:

```
1-000235
10-100364
9-123456

etc.
```

I would want the sorted result to return:

```
1-000235
9-123456
10-100364
```

I have a test VB.Net app I am trying to figure out how to do this:

```
Using ctx As New EFWeb.MaverickEntities
    Dim myparts = ctx.parts.
                        OrderBy(Function(e) e.partnumber).
                        ToList()

    For Each pt As part In myparts
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pt.partnumber, pt.description)
    Next
End Using
```

I tried doing: `CInt(e.partnumber.Split("-")(0))` to force sorting for the first segment of the partnumber, but errored out because of the the compiler did not like the array referrence for the result of the Split() call.

If anybody knows of a good current reference for LINQ to Entities ... that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show 3 segments sample pls? And can you show your real code, pls. What you have done so far?

Comment: 3-segment part numbers example would be: 9-123456-20, 9-123456-24, etc.  All segment parts refactor to Int32.

Comment: Thanks. And how to sort them? by the first segment digits too?

Comment: I don't see any c# or vb.net code in your question, nor do I see linq. What I do see is sql code. 
Anyway, this isn't a conundrum at all once you realize that sorting strings that happens to contain digits only is not the same as sorting integers. `1, 9, 10` is the expected results if the values are ints, but `"1", "10", "9"` is to be expected when the values are strings.

Comment: This SQL code is using *string* ordering, where `"010"` will always appear before `"1"`. It's also *very* slow as the server can't use any indexes and has to scan the entire table, split the numbers and only then order the results. If you want to order those *striings* as numbers you'd have to use `cast` to convert them to numbers, eg `ORDER BY cast(split_part(partnumber, '-',1) as int), cast(split_part(partnumber, '-',2) as bigint)`

Comment: Thank you for the response Zohar.  Yes, the partnumber segments are expected to be sorted as if they were integers, not strings.  Cetin answered exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share your Linq code. Anyway I would get the data to client side and then do the ordering. In C#:

```
var result = ctx.Parts.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => new {p, pnSplit = p.PartNumber.Split('-')})
    .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.pnSplit[0]))
    .ThenBy(x => int.Parse(x.pnSplit[1]))
    .Select(x => x.p);
```

In VB it should be:

```
Dim result = ctx.Parts.AsEnumerable()
        Select(Function(p) New With {p, .pnSplit = p.PartNumber.Split("-"c)}).
        OrderBy(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.pnSplit(0))).
        ThenBy(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.pnSplit(1))).
        Select(Function(x) x.p)
```

Note the integer.Parse. Otherwise it would be alphabetic sort.

Comment: Perfect!  That is exactly what I was looking for.